# JSON get highest to lowest value data multi array

Tags: php, sorting, facebook-graph-api, multidimensional-array

Hello whew im stack in this problem.... arranging value from highest to lowest in json data values

pastebin - `http://pastebin.com/yjFUfdJW` for the codes

whew i just want to sort the **likes** *highest* to *lowest*... whew anyone has a solution for it? :) pleas help.. :)

Comment: Whew: Used to express surprise, relief, or a feeling of being very hot or tired.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of PHP's sort functions for array sorting on the array-value of your JSON?

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort your associative array and maintain the correlation between array elements, you need to use [asort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php).

```
...

$like[] = array(
    'uid' => $uid[$i],
    'likes' => $datacount
);

foreach($like as $userlikes)
{
   // Sort array numerically
   asort($userlikes, SORT_NUMERIC);
}

...
```